# Android: Is there any way to tell if a contact is on Whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, whatsapp

I'm developing this android application and I would like to implement a kind of shortcut to an Whatsapp conversation activity, based on a contact in the user's contact list. But for now, I'm not even able to tell whether this contact is on whatsapp or not.

I have searched about it but I couldn't find anything useful.

Is there any way to do it? I would really appreciate any support.